# Can JInja templates be dumped into strings?

Tags: python, jinja2

I looked up dump in the Jinja2 API:

> Dump the complete stream into a file or file-like object. Per default unicode strings are written, if you want to encode before writing specify an encoding.

I am unable to find a file-like object that I could dump back into a string. Does anyone know a workaround for this?

Edit: I normally put the output in a file--but in a separate case I am appending the output to an e-mail.

Comment: Calling `.render()` returns a string.

Comment: (And the standard python file-like object that writes to a string is called [StringIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO).)

Comment: template engines are made to produce strings!

Comment: When you have something in your `Template()` object that is causing an error, it'd be nice to be able to see the string before it is rendered. It's the call to `.render()` that raises the error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not sure why you are looking at the streaming API for templates. Just render the template directly. From the [*Basics* section](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#basics) of the API documentation:

> To render it with some variables, just call the `render()` method:
>
> ```
> print template.render(the='variables', go='here')
> ```

The method returns a Unicode string. From the [`Template.render()` documentation](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.Template.render):

> This will return the rendered template as unicode string.

The `.dump()` method only applies to [*template streams*](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.environment.TemplateStream), objects produced by the [`Template.stream()` method](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/api/#jinja2.Template.stream); you shouldn't need to worry about those when all you wanted was a single string.

Even so, if you wanted a string from a stream, just join the chunks:

```
template_stream = template_obj.stream()
rendered = ''.join(template_stream)
```

Last but not least, if you still need an in-memory file object, look no further than [`io.StringIO()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.StringIO):

```
import io

fileobj = io.StringIO()
template_stream = template_obj.stream()
template_stream.dump(fileobj)
rendered = fileobj.getvalue()
```

Internally, `.dump()` is implemented as a loop over `self`, writing each chunk to the file object.

Comment: Thank you, I was missing file.get_model() as an argument for render.